# Como habilitar botón apenas se seleccionen archivos

Tags: html, input-file

Estoy cargando dos archivos separados a mi server uno corresponde a un XML y el otro a un archivo PDF pero quisiera que al seleccionar ambos archivos se habilite el botón para Subir Documentos, el siguiente es el código con el construyo los `input` y el botón de Subir Documentos.

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required>
              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="pdfToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo PDF:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="file" name="pdfToUpload" id="pdfToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required>
              </div>
                    </div>      
              </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Subir Documentos</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Quisiera saber si existe una manera de habilitar el botón de Subir Documentos solo hasta el momento en el que ambos input se encuentre seleccionado los archivos para subir.

Answer (score 4):

Sólo con HTML5, dentro del input `type="file"` se puede agregar: `required=""`. Lo que hace este es que, si no hay nada escrito o seleccionado, al precionar submit, salta un mensaje sobre éste input.

Ejemplo:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="">
 <input type="file" required="">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Ahora, tenemos el **submit** en `disabled` por defecto. Para activar el **submit** cuando se aya seleccionado un archivo, el botón o input `submit` debe estar activo.

> En este caso, no es necesario poner el **botón** `submit` dentro del `form`, porque actuará mediante **JavaScript**.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="">
 <input type="file" id="file" required="">
 <br>
 <button type="submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" disabled="">Enviar</button>
</form>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("file"); 
input.addEventListener('change', check); 

function check(event) { 
 var verificar = this.files.length == 0 ? true : false;   
 var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar"); 
 enviar.disabled = verificar;
}
</script>
```

Esto debería solucionar el problema. Ya te toca adaptar a tus necesidas y estilos (yo usé de referencia estilos de **bootstrap**).

Answer (score 1):

La solución que te propongo es:

1- Agregarle la propiedad `disabled` al botón `Subir Documentos`, ya que al inicio no debería tener documentos cargados.

2- Crear una función que detecte un cambio en los `inputs` y si ambos tienen un archivo cargado, cambie el valor `disabled` del botón `Subir Documentos` a false, para de esta forma habilitarlo. A esta función la llamé `uploadEnable`.

3- Asignarle la función `uploadEnable` al evento `onChange` de cada uno de los `inputs`

> Eso sería todo para hacer lo que queres. Y si queres que el botón `Cancelar` limpie los `inputs` y vuelva a deshabilitar el boton `Subir Documentos`, creé la funcion `cancelUpload` que lo único que hace es vaciar el valor de los inputs, y vuelve a llamar a la función `uploadEnable`. (Cabe aclarar que es necesario volver a llamar a esta funcion, porque el evento `onChange` que tienen asignados los inputs no detectan un cambio de value de la manera que lo estamos haciendo en la función `cancelUpload`. Eso esta explicado en el primer párrafo de la documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

```js
// Acá declaro y asigno las variables que voy a necesitar. Los dos inputs y el botón de submit
const inputXml = document.getElementById("XmlToUpload");
const inputPdf = document.getElementById("pdfToUpload");
const uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload");

// Esta es la función que se encarga de detectar, luego de cada cambio en los inputs, si debe o no habilitar el botón para subir el documento. La debo conectar a cada input con el método onChange.
function uploadEnable(){
   const enableButton = inputXml.files.length + inputPdf.files.length === 2 ? true : false;
   uploadButton.disabled = enableButton ? false : true;
}

// Esto es para cancelar la carga, se lo asigné al evento onClick del boton Cancelar. No lo pediste pero me parece que asi queda mas completo el formulario.
function cancelUpload(){
  inputXml.value = "";
  inputPdf.value = "";
  uploadEnable();
}
```

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
         <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required onChange="uploadEnable()">
       </div>
  </div>
            
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="pdfToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo PDF:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="file" name="pdfToUpload" id="pdfToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required onChange="uploadEnable()">
      </div>
  </div>      


  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button onClick="cancelUpload()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Subir Documentos</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los argumentos para *venderte* mi respuesta son:

1. No hace falta que toques tu HTML actual
2. Puedes agregar tantos `<input>` del tipo **file** como desees en el *HTML* sin tener que retocar el **javascript** pues ya lo tiene en cuenta
3. Al pulsar el botón `Cancelar`, además de salir del modal resetearás los campos `input` correctamente y así no volverán a aparecer llenos si regresas al modal

Aquí el código a agregar como javascript en tu página:

```
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']");
let botonSubir = document.getElementById("upload");
let botonCancelar = document.querySelector(".modal-footer button:first-child")

botonSubir.disabled = true

function activarSubirDocumentos() {
  let todos = 0
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.files.length === 1) {
      todos += 1
    }
  })
  botonSubir.disabled = (todos == inputs.length) ?
    false :
    true
}

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  activarSubirDocumentos()
}, false))

botonCancelar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  form.reset()
  activarSubirDocumentos()
}, false)
```

Y aquí un ejemplo de su uso con 3 **input** (repito, funciona con tantos *input* del tipo *file* como necesites):

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']");
let botonSubir = document.getElementById("upload");
let botonCancelar = document.querySelector(".modal-footer button:first-child")

botonSubir.disabled = true

function activarSubirDocumentos() {
  let todos = 0
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.files.length === 1) {
      todos += 1
    }
  })
  botonSubir.disabled = (todos == inputs.length) ?
    false :
    true
}

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  activarSubirDocumentos()
}, false))

botonCancelar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  form.reset()
  activarSubirDocumentos()
}, false)
```

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="pdfToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivos PDF:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="file" name="pdfToUpload" id="pdfToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required>
      <input type="file" name="pdfToUpload2" id="pdfToUpload2" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Subir Documentos</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple con Javascript.

Ejemplo:

```js
var docs;

function verifica_archivos(e){
    docs--;
    if(docs==0){
    $("#upload").removeAttr('disabled')
                .removeClass('btn-outline-secondary')
                .addClass('btn btn-success');
    }    
}
function SubirArchivos(){
  $('#mimodal').modal('toggle');
  Swal.fire({
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Archivos Cargados',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 1500
   })
}
function vermodal(){
  docs=2;
  $('#mimodal').modal('toggle');
  $('#mimodal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function(e){
    document.getElementById('subir_archivos').reset();
  });
  document.getElementById('subir_archivos').reset();
  $("#upload").attr('disabled','disabled')
              .removeClass('btn-success')
              .addClass('btn btn-outline-secondary');
}
$('#mimodal').modal('toggle');
$('#VerModal').click(vermodal);
$('#upload').click(SubirArchivos);
$("input:file").change(verifica_archivos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


<div id="mimodal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
<form id="subir_archivos" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Ejemplo Funcional</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="pdfToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo PDF:</label>
             <div class="col-sm-8">
               <input type="file" name="pdfToUpload" id="pdfToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required>
              </div>
            </div>      
           </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Subir Documentos</button>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
  </div>
    <button id="VerModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Subir Archivos
</button>
```

veo que estas usando modal de bootstrap
así que te dejo un ejemplo con ello;
con la limpieza de las variables y un plus.

Answer (score -1):

Si necesitas un botón de **submit** fuera del input, en este caso en tu `.modal-footer`, entonces, agrega una id en tu **form** así: `<form id="miId">`; y en el botón a enviar en el footer: `<button type="submit" form="miId">`.

Si esto no te funciona, usa jQuery así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("#upload").on("click", function() {
 
 $("#miId").submit();
 
 });
 
});
```

Comment: Aun no logro resolver este requerimiento, es posible que se pueda adaptar el código que agregaste como al código de mi pregunta inicial ?

Comment: Disculpa la demora. Voy agregar otra respuesta y darte dos opciones.